# Refresh or add ascx control from another ascx control

Tags: c#, user-controls, ascx

I am working on an asp .net project and i have a main ascx control which is divided by two RadSpliters. On load of the main.ascx the app is loading two other controls, the control1.ascx and control2.ascx. In the control1 i have a treeview and on selected node of the treeview i want to reload the control2.ascx. Is there a way to do this. Below i am pasting the code that i am using to do that but is not working. Any help or suggestions please?

```
  public partial class Control1: System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
        protected void TreeView1_SelectedNodeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BrowseProject b = new BrowseProject();
        b.load();
    }




public partial class MainControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
            public void load()
        {
                Control codeEditor = Page.LoadControl("Control2.ascx");
            PlaceHolder4.Controls.Clear();
            PlaceHolder4.ID = "PlaceHolder4";
            PlaceHolder4.Controls.Add(codeEditor);

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public interface IReload{
    public void reload();
}

public partial class Control2: System.Web.UI.UserControl, IReload
{

}

public partial class Control1: System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    IReload _r;

    public IReload setReload
    {
      set { _r = value; }
    }


    protected void TreeView1_SelectedNodeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BrowseProject b = new BrowseProject();
        b.load();
        if(_r != null){
            _r.reload();
        }
}

public partial class MainControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
        public void load()
    {
        Control codeEditor = Page.LoadControl("Control2.ascx");
        PlaceHolder4.Controls.Clear();
        PlaceHolder4.ID = "PlaceHolder4";
        PlaceHolder4.Controls.Add(codeEditor);

        c.setReload(codeEditor);
    }
```

Comment: yea but what type is c ?? Moreovr i get an error on setReload methid saying Inconsistent accessibility: property type '.' is less accessible than property

Comment: c is type Control1 , sorry :D